# Is there a NuGet package that contains a semantic version parser in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, semantic-versioning

I found this [blog post](http://www.michaelfcollins3.me/blog/2013/01/23/semantic_versioning_dotnet.html) and the related [Gist](https://gist.github.com/mfcollins3/4624831). The author does not appear to have created a corresponding NuGet package.

Anyone aware of a NuGet package that already exists?

For reference, [here](http://semver.org/) is the specification for semantic versioning.

Comment: You can use [System.Management.Automation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation/) — The Microsoft implementation of semantic versioning: [SemanticVersion Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.semanticversion).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turns out that the answer was right under my nose. NuGet.Core itself contains a [SemanticVersion class](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2/blob/2.13/src/Core/SemanticVersion.cs) with a TryParse method.

And, you can, in fact, install NuGet.Core via NuGet. :P

**Updated (4/30/2018)**: changed the link per guidance from @JeroenWiertPluimers.

Comment: In the mean time, it has moved to https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2/blob/2.13/src/Core/SemanticVersion.cs

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers thanks, i changed the link to the `master` branch instead of the specific version that you linked

Comment: I wish there was a way to refer to the default branch as that one changes over time: the file on `2.13` is 2 years younger than the one on `master`.

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers ok, didn't know that. i reverted the link to your specific one. thank you.

Comment: The most popular nuget package is now https://www.nuget.org/packages/Semver/

Comment: The latest Nuget version is now in [Nuget.Versioning](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Versioning)

Comment: There's [one in PowerShell SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.semanticversion) now. Might be too heavy of a depencency to bring on just for this but could be useful if you already use PowerShell SDK.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I am aware of.

However, the .NET builtin [Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx) class is perfectly happy to parse a version number compliant with the semantic versioning specification linked to in your question. It will return an object whose value for the Revision number is -1.

Comment: I don't think `Version` handles pre-release suffixes.

Comment: I missed that part, you are right. Sorry about that.